# How to use NOW() without using the user's computer's date

Tags: php

Ok, here's the deal :

I got 2 dates : NOW (29/11/2017 00:05) and (for example) 29/11/2017 01:05

```
$DateNow = new DateTime("now", $tz);
$DateEnd = new DateTime($jobtime['endjob'], $tz); // $tz is the time zone
$TimeLeft = $DateNow->diff($DateEnd);
if ($TimeLeft->d > 0) {
    echo 'End of the job !';
}
```

I would like to do something when NOW is at 01:05.
How do I restrain the user from modifying his computer's date in order to "cheat" ?

Thanks and sorry for lack of code, this question is quite short.

**EDIT** : My bad, the reason I could change the date manually was because I was on localhost.

Comment: Currently it will use the date of the ***server*** where PHP is executed. If you want to use another date then you must first set the timezone value.

Comment: I think that all [tag:php] is server side and it does not meant by the client.

Comment: You mistakenly feels that because you are working from the localhost where the server has the same clock of the client.

Comment: Oh gosh, I feel dumb. Thanks you SaidbakR for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

just make sure that `$jobtime['endjob']` comes from a reliable source, like your own database where the user has no write access, as opposed to coming from user-supplied variables like $_POST/$_GET/$_COOKIE.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: @wp78de no, it's not a comment, its a valid answer, this is exactly how you `restrain the user from modifying his computer's date in order to "cheat" `, as was the question.

Comment: @mickmackusa i disagree, see the comment i made to wp78de above.

Comment: You may ask the OP about the source of `$jobtime ['endjob']` if you are curious, but your advice is supplemental to the question asked -- so I think your post is better placed as a comment.   The OP is confusing serverside and clientside data as you will read from other commenters.  The question is flawed.